# How to generate random string from a collection of strings in Java?

Tags: java, string, button

Suppose I have a collection of 10 names. And on clicking a button the program should generate a random name from that collection. How is it achieved?

Comment: What kind of collection do you have? `List`, `Set`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose I have a collection of 10 names.

```
String[] names = new String[10];
// Make sure you init the array
```

> And on clicking a button the program should generate a random name
>   from that collection.

*I assume by generate a random name from that collection you mean chose a random name from that collection.*

```
private String onButtonClicked() {
return names[getRandomNumber(0, names.length - 1);];

}

private static int getRandomNumber(int begin, int end) {
  Random generator = new Random();
  return generator.nextInt(end - begin + 1) + begin;
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: An array is not a collection.

Comment: @Bohemian he did not state what kind of collection, and since he provided a finite amount of objects he would like to store in that collections, I assumed it to be an array.

Comment: In java [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) has this specific meaning.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have a collection (List) of Strings:

```
List<String> list;
```

Then to get a random one:

```
Collections.shuffle(list);
String random = list.get(0);
```

Actually you could use any element of the shuffled list, but the first (`.get(0)`) seems the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

You can just try something like

```
list.get((int) (Math.random() * list.size()))
```

If you don't have a `List`, but another type of collection that does not support indexing, you can still use something similar:

```
new ArrayList<>(col).get((int) (Math.random() * col.size()))
```